# Полное обтекание блоков на CSS

Tags: html, css

Злравствуйте, можно ли сделать полное обтекание блоков на css, как в гуглкартинках, например?
http://jsfiddle.net/shdobyzd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать библиотеку [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) или [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

---

Можно [посмотреть результат](http://jsfiddle.net/shdobyzd/1/) того, как это будет выглядеть. В примере изменяйте размер ширины фрейма "Result"

Comment: @Deonis, воспользовался. Что-то не работает на локалке.
http://pastebin.com/JAuqDxgq

Comment: @GreenMonster, сделайте чтобы css был над скриптами. PS. Title у сайта весёлый :)

Comment: @GreenMonster, 

    $(function(){
        $('#container').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.block'
        });
    });

Comment: @MasterAlex, @Deonis, ох уж этот javascript, не работает из-за любой мелочи. Спасибо, братишки.

>P.S. Title у сайта весёлый :)
Мне тоже нравится :3